# How to import custom local tokenizer function into SpaCy config file

Tags: nlp, spacy, tokenize

I am training a spaCy pipeline from scratch for a new language.

I have a pre-written function to tokenize text in a language not included as an out-of-the-box tokenizer for spaCy. The language has a similar written logic to Vietnamese, so I instantiated a spaCy model in Vietnamese first, and then tried to customize components of the config file post-hoc. What I want to do is plug in my custom tokenization function into the config file (in python code this would be as easy as an "import" statement), but I get an error saying "if you are using a custom function, make sure your code is available." I have tried importing the code into different scripts and it works, so it is definitely available locally. I sense that I am just missing something about the syntax of a cfg file.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do, up to the tokenizer part of the config file:

```
train = conllu_converted/train.spacy
dev = conllu_converted/train.spacy
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null
tokenizer = custom_tokenizer

[system]
gpu_allocator = null
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "vi"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","tagger","morphologizer","trainable_lemmatizer","parser"]
batch_size = 1000
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null

[nlp.tokenizer]
@tokenizers = custom_tokenizer.tokenize
use_pyvi = false
```

And a default example would be like the one below:

```
train = conllu_converted/train.spacy
dev = conllu_converted/train.spacy
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null
tokenizer = custom_tokenizer

[system]
gpu_allocator = null
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "vi"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","tagger","morphologizer","trainable_lemmatizer","parser"]
batch_size = 1000
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null

[nlp.tokenizer]
@tokenizers = custom_tokenizer.tokenize
use_pyvi = false
```

I would like to be able to import a custom tokenizer function directly into a spaCy config file. The error message indicates that this should be possible, but I'm missing a step in the documentation and I can't find it.

Comment: See: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#custom-tokenizer-training